# Why use the `go` keyword when calling a function?

Tags: go

I was going through an example of a TCP server. They defined a function and called it with:

```
go handleRequest(conn)
```

I thought it was weird seeing the `go` keyword, so I tried it without:

```
handleRequest(conn)
```

To my surprise, this worked!

- If both work the same way, why use the `go` keyword at all?
- If they work differently, what is the difference?
- Is there a certain style guideline to use, or should you just use personal preference?

Comment: `go fn()` runs `fn` in the background, so the goroutine that launched it can accept other connections and handle other requests while the first `handleRequest()` is still running.

Comment: Go check out https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements -- not sure I'd leave the question up, may get downvoted for lack of research effort.

Comment: @chilemagic, note that "Go Statements", and the term "goroutine" are defined on the exact same page you read about the "Go" keyword.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`go` starts a *goroutine*, which is managed by `golang` run-time.

It can either run on the current OS thread, or it can run on a different OS thread automatically.

You can refer to basic `golang` documents for this, for example, one item in Google search keyword `goroutine` is [golang concurrency](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/10).

Comment: Never heard the word `goroutine` before since I'm new to Go so I didn't know to search that. Thanks!

Comment: @chilemagic to see the difference in action, try connecting twice (at the same time) to your server.  You will find that without the word go, you will not accept the second tcp connection until the first one is done

Answer (score 7):

When you use the Go keyword before a func ure making that func run into a goRoutine, is like a Java Thread, and is the go way for concurrency, more info [here](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines). Good Luck

Comment: True in outline, different in details--Java threads are OS threads, but goroutines do some different stuff under the hood to try and reduce the time and memory costs of having lots of them or switching between them (with implications for some other things in the language).

Comment: that is why i said LIKE because they are similar to a very very light Threads, as rob pike said in one of his lectures.

Comment: yep yep, just trying to put potentially useful deatils where interested folks might see 'em.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency is not well documented in the go spec and it is one of the most powerful features of the language, the `go` keyword is the starting point when you are building concurrent software and not procedural software in go.

You need to look at channels as well to better understand this concept.

When you removed the `go` keyword, you made the function call procedural.

Check out the talk by Rob Pike (Creator of Go) on concurrency in golang.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs&t=1198s&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers