# Goroutine works even I set runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1). Why?

Tags: go

This simple example prints "done", "finished". How it's possible in case then we have only one physical thread limited by runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)? Go 1.19

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    done := false

    go func() {
        done = true
        fmt.Println("done")
    }()

    for !done {
    }
    fmt.Println("finished")
}
```

Comment: 'go func()...)' Is not a thread, it's a goroutine; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006856/why-use-the-go-keyword-when-calling-a-function

Comment: I know, but its start by scheduler, which should work in parallel with main thread. In this case we have only one thread and in the theory scheduler can't  start goroutine.

Comment: @Volker could you tell me what I'm wrong about?

Comment: Go routines take turns running on the available threads, and can change which thread they run on. The only way I'm aware of to reliably change this behavior is to call `runtime.LockOSThread()` in `init()`. Iirc there were (are?) some obscure ways to send a go routine into a spin lock where it cannot yield execution to the scheduler, but those are generally not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GOMAXPROCS(1)` does not limit the program to a single thread. [What does it do?](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime)

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute **user-level** Go code **simultaneously**. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code;

Assuming that the scheduler is not considered "user-level Go code" in this context, it would not be constrained by this number (1).

Even if user code is really occupying all the available threads, user code can still often be [preempted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) to allow other code to run. See the comment in [`preempt.go`](https://go.dev/src/runtime/preempt.go) for more details.

---

1. Maybe "user-level" here is meant in the sense of user code vs. kernel code. In that case, the Go runtime scheduler is obviously not kernel code, but it would seem to be redundant to call it "user-level Go code".

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing to see so many negative ratings. At the same time, no one noticed that the reason for the change in the behavior of the go scheduler in 14.1 (https://go.dev/doc/go1.14 ) "goroutines are now asynchronously preemptible". This code should hang in versions up to 14.1 and work in later versions.

Comment: it did work in older version of go but in some edge cases it could dead lock. This was fixed in go 1.14. which matters little since the oldest supported version of go is 1.17